# SwiftUI / Unknown padding in VStack / Whitespace?

Tags: swiftui

I have refractured a view, where I use a ZStack to get a background on the complete stack.
From there on I have a "overlay" with a VStack, which have a alignment of .leading.
But, I have a unknown "padding" or "whitespace" on the leading side.
I want to get rid of it and have the VStack with Category, Value, etc. on the leading side.

Code and picture below:

```
ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Image("e1")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 176, height: 180)
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Category")
                        Text("Value")
                        HStack {
                            Text("Days until Task")
                            Text("2")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .opacity(0.8)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 176, height: 180)
        .background(Color(hue: 0.0, saturation: 0.599, brightness: 0.831))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
```

[image: Problem in the gray opacity VStack]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add alignment when setting max width on the `VStack`:

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Category")
    Text("Value")
    HStack {
        Text("Days until Task")
        Text("2")
    }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // <- HERE
```

[image: Bonzai]

Comment: My savior! Thanks! I wouldn't have thought of putting that on the frame.

Comment: You're welcome Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Honor to whom honor is due. :-)